# New commit on Github only few file from all

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have new project in the android-studio. I want to commit the project on the github, I did with VCS - import into version control - share project on github. The problem is, in the repository its only showing the directory like this below:

### [image]

**My repository:**
[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: check if .gitignore is there then check it's content

Answer (score 0):

To update some specific File to the git

1.Launch **git bash** by right-clicking on the folder on your local system in which you have ".git folder".
2. Run command "git status". --->Command to check if you have modified the required files and saved it 
3. Run command **git commit -m "<**
4.Run command "git push" -- this will commit your changes to the server